# On complex form of von Mises distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

The PDF of von Mises distributin is
$$p_{\text{vM}}(\mu,\kappa;\theta)=\frac{1}{2\pi I_0(\kappa)}\exp\left\{\kappa(\cos(\theta-\mu)\right\}.$$
I would like to understand how to rewrite it in "canonical" complex form, i.e. in terms complex phase $z=\exp(i\theta)$. I can simply represent cosine in terms of complex quantities,
$$\kappa\cos(\theta-\mu)=\frac{\kappa e^{-i\mu}}{2}z+\frac{\kappa e^{+i\mu}}{2}\bar{z}$$
and I do not understand how can I simplify it further. So, I have
$$p_{\text{vM}}(q;z)=\frac{1}{2\pi I_0(|q|)}\left(\frac{1}{2}(\bar{q}z+q\bar{z})\right),\quad q\equiv\kappa e^{i\mu}.$$

**P.S.:** To understand what is "canonical" in some sense, let consider wrapped Cauchy distribution,
$$p_{\text{wC}}(r,\phi;\theta)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{1-r^2}{1-2r\cos(\phi-\theta)+r^2},$$
which can be "complexified" by introducing $w\equiv re^{i\phi}$,
$$p_{\text{wC}}(w;z)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{1-|w|^2}{|w-z|^2}.$$